# Impossible to set width for a SELECT element using CSS

Tags: html, css

It is just me, or using CSS to specify the width of a SELECT element does not take effect (in IE at least)?

The only way I can get the width to apply is to set it like:

```
<select id="pageSizes" name="size" style="width: 45px">
```

My CSS is:

```
#pageSizes
{
    width: 45px
}
```

Comment: Working fine for me; http://jsfiddle.net/3nMjD/

Comment: Works for me in IE 8. Are you missing something?

Comment: Likewise: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/DG37r/

Comment: To clarrify, setting width on element works, using CSS and no width on element doesn't.

Comment: `<select id="pageSizes" name="size" style="width: 45px">` you're missing the semicolon in the style after 45px. Should look like `<select id="pageSizes" name="size" style="width: 45px;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in IE9 and IE7 compatibility mode ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEq8J)):

```
<select id="pageSizes" name="size">
    <option>8.5" x 11"</option>
    <option>6" x 10"</option>    
</select>
```

css:

```
#pageSizes
{
 width:45px;   
}
```

**[edit]** Judging by the behavior you've described, wherein an inline-style achieves the desired result, you've probably got a conflicting css rule somewhere. So, show us *all* of your css.

Comment: @xander-guerin Make sure you use the HTML5 DOCTYPE to [throw IE into "Almost standards mode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types): `<!DOCTYPE html>`